# flowplayer large size video is not playing

Tags: javascript, video, flowplayer

I have embedded flowplayer in my site but the flowplayer is not playing video with 321 MB size.

It is working fine with the small size videos. All videos are in MP4 formats and placed at Amazon cloud computing.

This is the code I am using to play those videos:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js/flowplayer/example/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js"></script>

<a href="amazon/url/of/video.mp4"
 style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px"  
 id="player"> 
</a>

flowplayer("player", "path/to/flowswf/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
    autoBuffering : false,      // set a Player property
    onError: function(errorCode, errorMessage) {
        alert(errorCode);
        alert(errorMessage);                       
    }
 });
```

Is it a limitation of flowplayer?

How can I play large size videos like 321 MB?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with FlowPlayer but have you tried setting `autoBuffering` to `true`? If it isn't buffering the video, won't it try to download all the bits upfront?

Comment: Does the Amazon CDN support streaming? Maybe this will help: http://flowplayer.org/tutorials/introduction-to-streaming-servers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) you need to use [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) to stream from Amazon. Looks like FlowPlayer needs to be [configured to use a RTMP plugin](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/streaming.html). Maybe this will help ;-)